# ¿Cómo crear variable cuyo nombre es variable en Bash?

Tags: bash

En Bash, quiero crear una serie de variables con un bucle `for`, que cuyo nombre contenga el valor de `i`:

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
for(( i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ )){
    proceso_$i=();
}
```

Lo que quiero es que las variables que me cree sean las siguientes:

- proceso_0
- proceso_1
- proceso_2
- proceso_3
- proceso_4

Answer (score 3):

Pare ello puedes usar [`declare`](http://ss64.com/bash/declare.html):

```
$ mivar="hola"
$ declare $mivar=23
$ echo $hola
23
```

En tu caso:

```
for(( i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ )){
    declare proceso_$i=XXX # lo que sea
}
```

Sin embargo, sería intersante saber cuál es tu finalidad última. Muy probablemente un array sería más práctico para conseguir lo que pretendes.

Comment: Lo que quiero hacer es simular una matriz en bash y creo que esto es la mejor forma de hacerlo.

Comment: @CarlosGonzalez tal vez puedes similarlo con una variable asociativa: [ve un ejemplo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31468914/1983854).

Comment: @CarlosGonzalez de todos modos, sería bueno que editaras tu pregunta inicial explicando exactamente qué quieres hacer.