# Uso de doble variable o variable concatenada en array devuelve sustitución errónea

Tags: array, bash

Mi intención es cambiar el siguiente código (se trata de hacer un ping a los hosts declarados en los diferentes arrays contenidos en el archivo hosts.sh. Este ping se hace por grupos, un grupo corresponde a un array).

Intento hacer la expansión de la variable $1 ó $ambito dentro de la instrucción for. pero no consigo hacerlo acertadamente.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

source hosts.sh
ambito=$1

if   [ "$ambito" == "" ]
then
    for i in ${docencia[@]}
    do
        fping -r 1 $i 2>1 | grep "alive"
    done
    if [[ -z $( for i in ${docencia[@]}; do fping -r 1 $i 2>1 | grep "alive"; done ) ]]
    then
        echo "Todos los equipos están apagados"
    else
        echo " "
    fi
elif [ "$ambito" == "teoria" ]
then
    for i in ${teoria[@]}
    do
        fping -r 1 $i 2>1 | grep "alive"
    done
    if [[ -z $( for i in ${iteoria[@]}; do fping -r 1 $i 2>1 | grep "alive"; done ) ]]
    then
        echo "Todos los equipos están apagados"
    else
        echo " "
    fi
elif [ "$ambito" == "i1" ]
then
    for i in ${i1[@]}
    do
        fping -r 1 $i 2>1 | grep "alive"
    done
    if [[ -z $( for i in ${i1[@]}; do fping -r 1 $i 2>1 | grep "alive"; done ) ]]
    then
        echo "Todos los equipos están apagados"
    else
        echo " "
    fi
...
else
    echo "Indíque un [grupo] válido." 
    echo "Uso: estado <grupo_id>."
    echo "Grupo_id: teoria/i1/i2/i3/redesa/redesb/laboratorio"
fi
```

Por este otro código:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

source hosts.sh
ambito=$1

for i in ${"$ambito"[@]}
do
    fping -r 1 $i 2>1 | grep "alive"
done
if [[ -z $( for i in ${"$ambito"[@]}; do fping -r 1 $i 2>1 | grep "alive"; done ) ]]
then
    echo "Todos los equipos están apagados"
else
    echo " "
fi
```

Pero me devuelve sustitución errónea. Si solo escribo ${ambito[@]} no expande el array.

Comment: ¿cómo ejecutas el script?

Comment: no me quedaba nada claro qué querías hacer, veo ahora que con "expandir" te referías a usar el nombre como variable

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo crear variable cuyo nombre es variable en Bash?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10148/c%c3%b3mo-crear-variable-cuyo-nombre-es-variable-en-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes declarar tu variable `ambito` [como referencia](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameters.html). En tu caso:

```
declare -n ambito=$1
```

Y luego cambias la linea del bucle por:

```
for i in ${ambito[@]}
```

Con eso ya te debería funcionar el script.